# Why my after update trigger is executing on insert although I have separate trigger for insert as well

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

```
/* trigger for update */
create trigger add_date
on students 
after update
as
    update students 
    set dtModify = getdate()
    where id = (select id from inserted)

/* trigger for insert */
create trigger add_date_insert 
on students 
after insert
as 
    update students 
    set dtEnter = getdate() 
    where id = (select id from inserted)
```

Comment: Well - your `AFTER INSERT` trigger updates the table - so that will then trigger the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger. ....

Comment: You need to do some reading on triggers... `Inserted` is a table and contains rows, potentially multiple rows (or none) and you need to handle that.

Comment: Could you suggest a possible solution for this.  how to restrict the update trigger on insert. Thanks

Comment: I know this is an exercise but please note, in the real world storing the modification information inline in the table is frequently insufficient - each update wipes out any previous information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - for the `INSERT` - I would use a `DATETIME2(3)` column with a **default constraint** - then you do not need a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
    // your columns here
    dtEnter DATETIME2(3)
        CONSTRAINT DF_Students_dtEnter DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME())
)
```

Now, each time you insert a row and you *do not* specify the `dtEnter` column in your list of columns to insert values into - it will automatically be set by SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Students (list-of-columns-WITHOUT-dtEnter)
VALUES (list-of-values)
```

For the update, you need to use a trigger - can't use a default constraint for that. Use this trigger - make sure to handle the fact that `Inserted` might contain multiple rows!

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_date
ON dbo.Students 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.students 
    SET dtModify = SYSDATETIME()
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, but They asked me to make a trigger for insert as well I know its not a good practice but its requirement could you suggest me any possible solution regarding this.

Comment: @jamilraza I highly recommend the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting confused by `inserted` then there is nothing to worry about. This table has the inserted row on which the trigger is struck.

Now there are only two such tables in SQL Server `inserted` and `deleted`

- In Case of Insert, `inserted` has the row inserted.
- In case of Delete, `deleted` has the row which is deleted.
- In case of Update, the row in question is first deleted and hence placed in `deleted` and then new row is inserted with updated data which you can find in table `inserted`. So you might think of update as a single operation when it's actually combination of two operations delete and insert.

If you want your trigger to run logic only in case of Update you can put a IF check like this:

```
If exists (Select * from inserted) and exists(Select * from deleted)
```

and place your trigger logic inside this block like this

```
If exists (Select * from inserted) and exists(Select * from deleted)
BEGIN
--Update Logic
END
If exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
BEGIN
--Inser Logic
END
```

Comment: "*the* row" - NO, NO, NO, NO, NO. This is the single most common mistake beginners make with triggers in SQL Server. Those tables can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. If you treat them as if they will only ever contain one row, you've just written a broken trigger.

Comment: How is this trigger broken. I just put  a check to differentiate insert and update. How does the number of rows in those table make the trigger broken?

Comment: Just because i was explaining using the simplest scenario to make it easy to understand, Makes the whole explanation broken?